# Selectoption value is not passed to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, selectoption

Status picklist values are : New,Pending,Closed.
  In onchange i am trying to pass selected picklist value . If i select New/Pending/Closed the value is passed to controller .But when i chose the Value 
  ",'-Remove Status-" it is not passed to the controller.

```
vf :
 <apex:actionFunction id="passStatus" name="passStatus" action="{!passStatus}" oncomplete="test();" rerender="table,rejectReason"/> 
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" onchange="checkStatus(this);" style="height: calc(1.875rem + (1px * 2));" id="rejectReason">    
<apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectOptions}"/>                       
</apex:selectlist>

function checkStatus(ev){
 /*logic here*/
  passStatus();
}
```

Apex :

```
 public List<SelectOption> getSelectOptions() {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult describeResult = Account.Status__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> entries = describeResult.getPicklistValues();
    optionsToReturn = new List<SelectOption>();
    optionsToReturn.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
    optionsToReturn.add(new SelectOption('','-Remove Status-'));
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry pEntry : entries) {
        if (pEntry.isActive()) {
            optionsToReturn.add(new SelectOption(pEntry.getValue(), pEntry.getLabel()));
        }
    }
    return optionsToReturn;
```

}

```
public void passStatus() {
    system.debug('InsidepassRejectReson'+selectedValue);
```

}

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is the *value*, the second is just the *label*. You need to make sure you use the correct value in the first parameter; that is the one that is sent to the controller.

```
optionsToReturn.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
optionsToReturn.add(new SelectOption('-Remove Status-','-Remove Status-'));
```

In this case, the first two values are represented by `null` and `'-Remove Status-'`.